# How to get all h3 content inside nested div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, web-scraping

I am working on jquery selector so my requirement is get h3 content, however as per site all have common class, there is no chance on unique class using which heading content to be fetched, So I want h3 data to be fetched

```js
$(".full_section_inner .vc_column_container").each((i, elem) => {
  console.log($(elem).find('.vc_column_container, .wpb_wrapper > h3').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full_section_inner">
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <a href="#" target="_self">
              <div class="vc_singley"><img width="900" height="529" alt="" alt="" /></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_empty_space" style="height: 20px">
          <span class="vc_empty_space_inner">
            <span class="empty_space_image"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><span >some value</span></a> H3 data here</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h5 style="text-align: center;">heading content</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <a href="#" target="_self">
              <div class="vc_singley"><img width="900" height="529" alt="" alt="" /></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_empty_space" style="height: 20px">
          <span class="vc_empty_space_inner">
            <span class="empty_space_image"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="#"><span >some value</span></a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h5 style="text-align: center;">heading content</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So above code I want to get all h3 text

Comment: Your code appears to be working fine - as you can see in the snippet I edited in to the question. Can you please be more specific about the problem, as well as the output you expect to see

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want to get text inside h3 currently text not mentioned in h3 but in my local code it is present

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make sense. The only text within your example `h3` HTML is `some value`, and this is what's being shown in the console.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I want  all h3 text inside each, but unable to get i.e empty value getting

Comment: This is my point - the demo code you've showed works. If it's not working for you then there's an error in your local version. Check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no man it is getting all html data, but I want only  h3 values "some value", not all html content

Comment: Have you even looked at the snippet I created, or read any of my previous comments?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes even i copied you snippet and run in my system.